# How to manage listview between two buttons

Tags: android

I have a button ,listview and another button.Initially listview have property gone so that button2 show below of button 1,when i click on button1 ,button 2 should set on bottom of that screen and list should be visible in between both buttons.....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/Button01"
            android:background="#ffffff" android:text="Button"
            android:layout_height="40dp"></Button>
        <ListView android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/llList"></ListView>
        <Button android:layout_height="40dp" android:text="Button"
            android:id="@+id/button" android:background="#ffffff"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"></Button>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**activity**

```
   package com.app.app.hello;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class HelloActivity extends Activity {


    ListView llList;
    Button btn2,btn1;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        llList=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.llList);

        llList.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        myAdapter adapter=new myAdapter();

        llList.setAdapter(adapter);

         btn2=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        Button btn1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);


        btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {


                llList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
    }

    class myAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {

        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 5;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            View row=View.inflate(HelloActivity.this,R.layout.list_row, null);
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return row;
        }

    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: initially i use gone property for listview ,on button click visible listview ,i dont want to give hight to listview,because of multiple device resolution ,i use fill-parent property on listview but problem is that i cant manage button below of listview and it should be at the bottom of screen....

Comment: Your ListView is "visible" but since it doesn't have any content there is nothing to display, so you cannot see it.

Comment: Set a background color to your ListView. That you can se if it's there or not. And, since if you haven't set an adapter to the list won't be visible.

Comment: i know there is no content in listview,i can bind it with content but problem is that how to grow listview till bottom of screen and above of second button on first button click..

Comment: Try to set fill_parent to your RelativeLayout height (I don't know if it will work) but I recomend you to use a LinearLayout instead of, because your layout is to simple with three horizontal lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this Activity code:

```
public class AbcActivity extends Activity {
    Button btn1, btn2;
    ListView lv1;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.two);

        btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
        btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        lv1  = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.llList);

        btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                lv1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams head1Params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                head1Params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
                btn2.setLayoutParams(head1Params);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

and Use Following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:id="@+id/Button01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:text="Button1" >
    </Button>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/llList"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Button01" >
    </ListView>

    <Button
        android:layout_below="@+id/llList"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="#123456"
        android:text="Button2" >
    </Button>

</RelativeLayout>
```